# How to extract part of an array in avro file in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

This is the format of the avro file I'm parsing:

```
var ttime: Long = 0;
var eTime: Long = 0;
var tids: String = "";
var tlevel: Integer = 0;
var tboot: Long = 0;
var rNo: Integer = 0;
var varType: String = "";
var uids: List[TRUEntry] = Nil;
```

List[TRUEntry] is the array I'm parsing. This is how I'm doing it.

```
    this.uids = Nil
    row.getAs[Seq[Row]]("uids")
    .foreach((objRow: Row) => 
      this.uids ::= (new TRUEntry(objRow))
    )
```

This is how I'm parsing the uids:

```
 this.uids    
.foreach((obj:TRUEntry) => {
  uInfo += obj.uId + " , " + obj.initM.toString() + " , "
})
```

How can I extract and pass obj.uid from the above array in the following code:

```
 val avroParsed = avroRow
    .map(x => new TRParser(x))
    .map((obj: TRParser) => ((obj.tids, **obj.uId**),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the following code :

```
val avroParsed = avroRow
    .map(x => new TRParser(x))
    .map((obj: TRParser) => {
      val tId = obj.source.trim
      var retVal: String = ""
      obj.uids
        .foreach((obj: TRUEntry) => {
          retVal += tId + "," + obj.uId.trim + ":"
        })
        retVal.dropRight(1)
    })
```

The value of tid and uid is saved as separate variables and then the variables can be processed in the 'for' loop.